# FacebookUtils showing multiple warnings

Tags: objective-c, facebook, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods

I just installed the `ParseFacebookUtils` pod via CocoaPods. In it brought multiple warnings which can be viewed below:

[image: CocoaPods Warning]

Are these warnings things I can deal with, or should I simply accept the fact they use deprecated methods?

Would it be wise to go into the pod myself and change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The podfile in question has deprecated in favour of `ParseFacebookUtilsV4` at the time of writing.